# C++ Why is my singleton not maintaining member value

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm learning C++ and I'm trying to implement a Singleton. Here's the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Configuration{

    Configuration(){
        languageName = "English";
    };

    public:
    std::string languageName;

    static Configuration& instance(){
        static Configuration _instance;
        return _instance;
    }
};

int main(){
    auto config = Configuration::instance();
    config.languageName = "Deutsch";
    std::cout<<config.languageName<<std::endl;//Deutsch

    auto config2 = Configuration::instance();
    std::cout<<config.languageName<<std::endl;//Deutsch
    std::cout<<config2.languageName<<std::endl;//English
    std::cout<<(&config == &config2)<<std::endl;//0
}
```

I expected that if I set the value of language on one instance, the same value will be held by a second instance since both instances are in fact the same.

But in the above code `config2` and `config` have different values for `languageName`. What is the reason for this? I'm following the code from a tutorial.

Comment: _"will be held by a second instance"_ Shouldn't there be a single instance of a singleton?

Comment: Delete the copy constructor and assignment operator. That way you can only catch references rather than accidentally making copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both instances are in fact the same

No, they're not the same instance. Even `Configuration::instance()` returns reference, the variables in `main()` are not declared as reference too, so the returned reference will be copied. You need to declare them to be reference to avoid copying. Such as,

```
auto& config = Configuration::instance();
    ~
auto& config2 = Configuration::instance();
    ~
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/QGQG98197)

BTW: To ensure there's only one instance, you might want to `delete` the copy/move constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Ah that make sense! Yes, the tutorial also mentions deleting copy and move - i was just experimenting as i went along. Thank you for your answer.